# Сравнить содержимое массивов между собой

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Есть массив в нем несколько массивов, каждый массив содержит в себе некоторое количество объектов, нужно сравнить содержимое этих объектов между массивами. 
Пример массива с объектами:

```
Array
(
   [136171] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 42681
                [group_id] => 11
                [name] => 44701
                [enabled] => 1
                [position] => 42681
                [is_auto] => 1
                [is_popular] => 0
                [group_name] => Цена
                [prefix] => Цена
                [postfix] => Р
                [show_prefix_in_frontend_filter] => 1
                [product_id] => 136171
                [export2yandex] => 0
                [sort_type] => position
                [css_class] => 
                [columns_count] => 1
                [mode] => range
                [name_yandex] => 
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 16021
                [group_id] => 13
                [name] => Bandini
                [enabled] => 1
                [position] => 50
                [is_auto] => 1
                [is_popular] => 1
                [group_name] => Бренд
                [prefix] => Бренд
                [postfix] => 
                [show_prefix_in_frontend_filter] => 0
                [product_id] => 136171
                [export2yandex] => 0
                [sort_type] => name_asc
                [css_class] => brand-block
                [columns_count] => 2
                [mode] => checkbox
                [name_yandex] => 
            )
...
)
)
```

Может у кого есть изящное решение данной задачи, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что значит "сравнить"? Полное тождество? Что делать с объектами если они "одинаковы"?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets которые одинаковые не интересны, а вот разницу записывать с ключом массива.

Comment: Переводите объекты в массивы и используйте `array_diff` ( http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php )

Comment: @YuriyProkopets мне нужно эти объекты сравнить в разных массивах, а не между собой.

Comment: Запускаем цикл по исходному массиву, на каждой итерации смотрим в массив с которым нужно сравнивать. Как получить разницу между объектами я уже написал.